# Can I use vector images in Android?

Tags: android

Can I use vector graphics in Android? I have to vector images, how can i use it as application icon and how can I connect it to ImageView in Android?

Comment: You can SVG images, but you need a 3rd party (free) library. App icons can't be vectorial by definition. All the SVG libraries provide methods to read the xml from the SVG files and make a bitmap out of it.

Comment: Actual info on how to use appcompat vectors - http://stackoverflow.com/q/40678947/7045114

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is "svg-android" for svg files support for Android, but not native. I don't think you can use it as application icon.

Latest source code: https://github.com/pents90/svg-android

Documentation: https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/

Answer (score 1):

From Android 5.0 (API level 21) you can use vector drawable in your app. You can use new Android Studio tool called: Vector Asset Studio. See link below for a complete explanation:

[Vector Asset Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html)

Comment: When answering with just a link, you should provide brief explanation *in the answer*, because if link happened to be broken, your answer would lost its value and most likely would be downvoted and deleted.