# How to properly use backwards compatible Vector Drawable with the latest Android Support Library?

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat, android-vectordrawable

Vector drawable has been added to Support Library not so long time ago and there were a lot of changes in the API since then: Gradle flags, initializer blocks, selectors, custom XML attributes etc. The question is - how to properly use it now (support lib v25) in these cases:

- ImageView
- TextView drawable
- Menu icon
- Notification icon

XML and programmatically.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Add the latest support lib to your app's `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
```

and add the following line in the same file:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    ...
}
```

Import vector image through [Vector Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#running).

*That's all, you are ready to go!*

---

### ImageView

**XML**

Use `app:srcCompat` attribute instead of `android:src`:

```
<ImageView
    ...
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_vector" 
    ... />
```

**Programmatically**

*Directly from resource id:*

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_drawable);
```

*Set as `Drawable` object (e.g. for tinting):*

```
Drawable vectorDrawable 
                = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.your_vector);
imageView.setImageDrawable(vectorDrawable);
```

And if you want to set tint:

```
DrawableCompat.setTint
             (vectorDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color));
```

---

### TextView drawable

**XML**

There is no simple solution: XML attribute `android:drawableTop(Bottom etc)` can't handle vector images on pre-Lollipop. One solution is to [add initializer block to activity and wrap vector into another XML drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html#setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled%28boolean%29). Second - [to define a custom TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40250753/7045114).

**Programmatically**

Setting resource directly doesn't work, you have to use `Drawable` object. Get it the same way as for `ImageView` and set it with the appropriate method:

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(vectorDrawable, null, null, null);
```

---

### Menu icon

There is nothing special:

```
<item
    ...
    android:icon="@drawable/your_vector"
    ... />

menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.your_vector);
```

---

### Notifications:

It's [impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37756967/7045114), you have to use PNGs :(

Comment: 1+ for both the cases.

Comment: `AppCompatResources.getDrawable` works well, thank you. Can someone tell me why `ContextCompat.getDrawable` doesn't work with the exact same code and gives me an error when using a vector?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true to your build.gradle file:

```
// Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

You’ll note this new attribute only exists in the version 2.0 of the Gradle Plugin. If you are using Gradle 1.5 you’ll instead use:

```
// Gradle Plugin 1.5  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     generatedDensities = []  
  }  

  // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
 }
```

You need to add srcCompat to your ImageView:

```
<ImageView  
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />
```