# Changing drawable color in android

Tags: android, animation

I have one image [image]

I want to animate this image like[image]

There are total 24segments and I want this change this image colour.
From android 21+ I can use vector but I need supports for android 15+.Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Anything stopping you trying to attempt this with AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat? http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html?m=1 however there are some caveats https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88

Comment: You CAN use vectors on api<21, check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678947/how-to-properly-use-backwards-compatible-vector-drawable-with-android-support-li/40678948#40678948