# VectorDrawable showing up as black in JellyBean

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I am using vector drawables all around the place in my app. Today I tested with a JellyBean device and they are all ignoring the color I defined in my XML.

This is an example of a Vector Drawable Im using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24"
        android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path android:fillColor="@color/colorWhite" android:pathData="M17,10.5V7A1,1 0 0,0 16,6H4A1,1 0 0,0 3,7V17A1,1 0 0,0 4,18H16A1,1 0 0,0 17,17V13.5L21,17.5V6.5L17,10.5Z" />
</vector>
```

And this is how they show up:

Jellybean:

[image: JellyBean]

MarshMallow:

[image: MarshMallow]

Comment: Instead of referencing to `@color` string. Try directly adding `#ffffff`.

Comment: Tell me, If its is working then you just need to add some lines in build.gradle and then you would be able to use the reference method.

Comment: @PradumnKumarMahanta it is working, but I would like to reference the colors by name, is it not possible?

Comment: how did you define `@color/colorWhite`?

Comment: Yeah, let me answer that.

Answer (score 1):

See for backward compatibility, you need to add this to your gradle,

```
// Gradle Plugin 2.0+
 android {
   defaultConfig {
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
 }
```

then you'd be able to use the reference method. This is to make the support library compatible with older versions.

This thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678947/how-to-properly-use-backwards-compatible-vector-drawable-with-android-support-li), explains how to use the same in all android versions and this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417843/how-to-use-vector-drawables-in-android-api-lower-21) explains the rest.

Regards.

Comment: If I enable this property, my app does not work on Pre KitKat devices

Comment: The second thread explains that. It should BTW, support library is now Backward Compatible to API 9. What is your Gradle Version?

Comment: 2.2.3 with support library 25.0.1

Comment: It should work then, What's the ERROR? Crash Log? or Doesn't Install?

Comment: Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector

Comment: I can't think of anything that would cause that. It's working perfectly fine for me. I just tried it.