# Hello World app crashes on 2.3.3 (API 10), but works fine on 5.1 (API 22)

Tags: android, crash

Using Android Studio I have created a very basic skeletal app. It works on android 5.1 API 22, but crashes on invocation on android 2.3.3 API 10.

Here is the crash log. It shows **resource not found exception** for abc_vector_test.xml file.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {com.myco.k5/com.myco.k5.MainActivity}: 
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020052
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:1651)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020052
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1977)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:602)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:388)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:202)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:711)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:131)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:155)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:209)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
at com.myco.k5.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)    
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:783)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1952)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:602) 
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:388) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:202) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:711) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195) 
at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:131) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:155) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:209) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71) 
at com.myco.k5.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have already tried some of the approaches (see code below).
Files are:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myco.k5" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout         
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"         
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"     
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"     
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"     
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView android:text="Hello World!" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.myco.k5;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

app's build.gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.myco.k5"
            minSdkVersion 10
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        dexOptions {
            incremental true
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    }

Top level build.gradle file:

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Please advice on how can this crash be resolved.

---

**SOLVED**: Solved this by using the following

1. In app level build.gradle file used

   android {
       // your entries here
       generatedDensities = []
   }
   // Flag notifies aapt to keep the attribute IDs around
   aaptOptions {
       additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
   }

   2. In the top level build.gradle file changed classpath from 1.4.0 to 1.5.0

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
// Earlier it was 1.4.0 here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly use backwards compatible Vector Drawable with latest Android Support Library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678947/how-to-properly-use-backwards-compatible-vector-drawable-with-latest-android-sup)

Comment: VishnuSP - I am not using abc_vector_test in my code at all. It seems to be an internal android file for which android is giving an error.

Comment: ok. Try using `buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"` or above.
Also have a look at [Support Vector Drawables] (https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

Comment: Tried using buildToolVersion "24.0.1".
This does not recognize         generatedDensities = []

I get 
Error:(25, 0) No such property: generatedDensities for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor_Decorated

Comment: **SOLVED** : Solved this by using the following in the top level (not app level) build.gradle file.
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    // Earlier it was 1.4.0 here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you have to enable the Vector Drawable to use it in old android versions. Add this in your `build.gradle` file (module app).

**For Gradle Plugin 2.0+**

```
android {
       defaultConfig {
         vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        }
     }
```

**For Gradle Plugin 1.5 or below**

```
 android {
      defaultConfig {
        // Stops the Gradle plugin’s automatic rasterization of vectors
        generatedDensities = []
      }
      // Flag notifies aapt to keep the attribute IDs around
      aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
      }
    }
```

After do that, you have to change your `ImageView` to use the compat src like that:

```
  <ImageView
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/abc_vector_test"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Luiz - I got errors in gradle sync on using either set of the lines in build.gradle file.


With vectorDrawables line from your input, I got this:
    Error:(14, 0) Could not find property 'vectorDrawables' on ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, ....



With generatedDensities line from your input I got this:


    Error:(14, 0) No such property: generatedDensities for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor_Decorated
...

Comment: Also, I do not have any ImageView in use with abc_vector_test in my code. It seems to be an internal android file for which android is giving an error.

Comment: @chris-banes - would you want to take a look at my question please?